# How to make toggle label with only css

Tags: javascript, html, css

I tried to make toggle label with html, css, javascript.

This is my code what I tried.

```js
function genre_itemclick(item){
          if(item.classList.contains('light_blue_border_button')) {
              item.classList.remove('light_blue_border_button');
              item.classList.add('light_blue_button');
          }
          else{
              item.classList.remove('light_blue_button');
              item.classList.add('light_blue_border_button');
          }
  }
```

```css
.light_blue_border_button{
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    border-radius: 10px;
    height: 30px;
    border:2px solid #3CDEBF;
    text-align: center; 
    color: #3CDEBF;
}
.light_blue_button{
    background-color: #3CDEBF;
    border:2px solid #3CDEBF;
    height: 30px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    text-align: center;
    color: #ffffff;      
}
```

```html
<div class="light_blue_border_button" onclick="genre_itemclick(this)">test</div>
```

But I want to make this function with only HTML and CSS.
So I tried like this.
But it does not work.

```css
body {padding:60px;}

.toggle-switch input[type=checkbox] {display:none}
.toggle-switch label {cursor:pointer;}
.toggle-switch label{
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    border-radius: 10px;
    height: 30px;
    border: 2px solid #3CDEBF; 
}

.toggle-switch input[type="checkbox"]:checked + label{
      background-color: #3CDEBF;
    border: 2px solid #3CDEBF;
    height: 30px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    text-align: center;
    color: #ffffff;
}
```

```html
<div class="toggle-switch">
  <input type="checkbox" id="chkTest" name="chkTest">
  <label>
    Test
  </label>
</div>
```

Please help me.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Just turn it into a checkbox and style it with the [:checked](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:checked) pseudo class

Comment: What have you tried? Also, div elements don't have an `href` property.

Comment: to be honest I don't think this is possible. Both HTML and CSS are styling languages so you're not supposed to be able to program any functionality with either of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `checkbox` and style it based of it's [checked](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:checked) state.

We then use a label to toggle the checkbox on and off. Since clicking on a label automatically focusses the corresponding input.

```css
/* Default styling */
label {
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    border-radius: 10px;
    height: 30px;
    border:2px solid #3CDEBF;
    text-align: center;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    color: #3CDEBF;
    padding: 6px 9px 7px 8px;
    margin-top: 20px;
    margin-left: 8px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

/* Hide checkbox (we use the label the trigger the checkbox) */
#foo {
  display: none;
}

/* Styling when checkbox is checked */
#foo:checked + label {
    background-color: #3CDEBF;
    border:2px solid #3CDEBF;
    height: 30px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    text-align: center;
    color: #ffffff;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    margin-top: 20px;
    margin-left: 8px;
    padding: 6px 9px 7px 8px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<input id="foo" type="checkbox" />
<label for="foo">test</label>
```

Comment: Your missing the [for](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/label) attribute so the `label` does not know what input it is associated with.

Comment: @Reyno I have been struggling and wondering to figure out how can a hidden input be accessed with a label for days. Referred tons of other questions but here is the explanation. If you miss `for` attribute on `label` it doesn't work

Answer (score 1):

Try this solution please. It will work for you very well.

```css
.toggle-switch input[type=checkbox] {display:none}
.toggle-switch label {cursor:pointer;}
.toggle-switch label{
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    border-radius: 10px;
    height: 30px;
    border: 2px solid #3CDEBF; 
}

.toggle-switch input[type="checkbox"]:checked + label{
      background-color: #3CDEBF;
    border: 2px solid #3CDEBF;
    height: 30px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    text-align: center;
    color: #ffffff;
}
```

```html
<div class="toggle-switch">
  <input type="checkbox" id="chkTest" name="chkTest">
  <label for="chkTest">
    Test
  </label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

In your try you forgot to tell the label `for` what checkbox it sould work!
`<label for="idOfInputCheckBox">` and `<input type="checkbox" id="idOfInputCheckBox" />`.

Or you just write the input inside of the label so it will be triggered if label will be clicked. I made an example:

```css
:root {
  --blue: #6495ed;
  --white: #fff;
}

label {
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
}
label input.toggleBox {
  display: none;
}
label .button {
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 20px 50px;
  margin: 10px auto;
  border: 1px solid var(--blue);
  border-radius: 10px;
  background-color: var(--blue);
}
label input.toggleBox:checked ~ .button {
  background-color: var(--white);
}
```

```html
<label>
  <input type="checkbox" class="toggleBox" />
  <span class="button">some Text.</span>
</label>
```

Comment: But when I click outside of the button, it is toggled.